# find maximum of 3 other rows in same array using 'for' for each value

Tags: matlab, for-loop, resize, max

I have 3 results for the same problems in the following array:

```
(0.0 0.0 0.2
 0.8 0.0 1.2
 2.9 1.6 4.3

 0.0 1.5 0.2
 0.0 0.0 0.4
 0.0 2.4 0.3

 0.4 0.3 6.2
 0.9 0.0 0.4
 0.3 0.0 1.2)
```

For example, one problem has the results 0.0 0.0 0.4 in positions (1,1) (4,1) (7,1). I am trying to find the maximum result in order to have only a 3x3 array:

```
for m=1:3
for n=1:3
sy(m,n)=max(sy(m,n), sy(m+3,n), sy(m+3*2,n));
end
end
sy=imresize(sy, [3 3]);
```

And I get MAX with two matrices to compare and a working dimension is
not supported.

Comment: `max(cat(3,A,B,C),[],3)` for arrays `A`, `B`, `C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your matrix is set up as follows:

```
sy =[0.0 0.0 0.2; 0.8 0.0 1.2; 2.9 1.6 4.3; 0.0 1.5 0.2 ;...
    0.0 0.0 0.4; 0.0 2.4 0.3; 0.4 0.3 6.2; 0.9 0.0 0.4; 0.3 0.0 1.2];
```

Then I think:

```
sy = max(reshape(sy',3,3,3),[],3)';
```

Achieves your desired result.

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration of `sy` be `M` instead? `M` in undefined at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I get an error 'To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.'  I think it's because I don't allways have a 3x3 3 problem. Let's see what I can get.

Comment: For example, instead of 3 results of 3x3, another time i have 3 results of 17x17.

Comment: GOT IT sy = max(reshape(sy',17,17,3),[],3)'; Thanks